# Monorepo didn't compile my file inside the folder

Tags: typescript, compilation, monorepo, nomachine-nx

hi guys i want to ask to you all, i have an issue when doing nx serve myapp, when i run this command i think the command not compile all my folder inside the src folder? my structure folder is like in the images, so when nx serve is done i got an error like this

> [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir
> '/Users/macbook/Documents/coding/office/template/first-monorepo/dist/packages/vokal/plugins']
> {   errno: -2,   code: 'ENOENT',   syscall: 'scandir',   path:
> '/Users/macbook/Documents/coding/office/template/first-monorepo/dist/packages/vokal/plugins'
> }

this is my tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["node"]
  },
  "exclude": ["jest.config.ts", "src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.test.ts"],
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
}
```

this is my tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../dist/out-tsc",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": ["jest", "node"]
  },
  "include": [
    "jest.config.ts",
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
this is my tsconfig.json
{
    "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
    "files": [
        "package.json"
      ],
    "references": [
      {
        "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
      },
      {
        "path": "./tsconfig.spec.json"
      }
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
      "baseUrl": "src",
      "rootDir": ".",
      "paths": {
        "@/*": ["*"],
        "@root/*": ["../*"],
        "@config": ["./config"],
        "@api/*": ["./adapters/api/*"],
        "@cli/*": ["./adapters/cli/*"],
        "@domain/*": ["./domain/*"]
      }
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  }
```

why i got thats error? can anyone tell me whats the problem?

[my structure folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2dOo.png)